How to make each copy of geometry nodes instance have a random number of blooming flowers?
I want to make a procedural lavender flower generator using curves.
I have developed a node system that generates a single section of bloom. It consists of several unopened flowers and several closed ones. In this system, I can control the number of blooming flowers.
I need that when a created instance is placed on a curve, each created copy of that instance has a random number of blooming flowers, not a fixed one.



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I'm sorry, I'm a beginner and may not have understood the rules of the forum very well. I will try to ask questions more correctly.

(Using Blender 4.2.4)
The randomized objects must be the last ones to be instanced (see dark pink node) ; all previous "spawning" points must be realized to support different data sets (see dark blue nodes).

(Blender 4.2.4+)

It worked, thank you very much!
